# How to write onclick="function()" and give the function param in php written html code

Tags: php, html, jquery

im having a really confusing problem passing param to a jquery function. i saw a lot of sloution but none work in my case. so please dont mark my post as duplicated unless my problem solved.

in my PHP code:

```
echo '<td onclick=" tabCaller( "customer", " id='.$row['id'].' " ) " >'.$row['id'].'</td>';
```

The html code should look like:

```
<td onclick="tabCaller("customer","id=1")"> 1 </td>
```

the Jquery Function:

```
function tabCaller(tabName, parameter = null){
    // do something

}
```

**the Problem is that my html codes looks like:**

```
<td onclick="tabCaller("customer",="" 'id="1')">#1</td>
```

Comment: `echo "<a onclick=\"tabCaller('customer','id=". $row['id']."') \">" . $row['id'] . "</a>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing three different languages on the same line of code is a recipe for quoting problems.  The browser is likely trying to make sense of all those double-quotes, since it uses double-quotes as start- and end-delimeters for element attributes.

Instead, use single-quotes for the JavaScript parts and just escape them in the PHP:

```
echo '<td onclick="tabCaller(\'customer\', \' id=' . $row['id'] . ' \')">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
```

Which should produce:

```
<td onclick="tabCaller('customer', ' id=1')">1</td>
```

Comment: "recipe for quoting problems" hahahah. thank you man. problem solved